# Drawing specific curves/planes

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, 3d

I want to submit a paper and the only thing that's left to do is to add some graphics. My deadline is on Wednesday/Thursday.

What I want to do is some basic curve/plane drawings. Here is an image:

[image]

I checked out the post about the big software list for drawings https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/software-for-drawing-geometry-diagrams and I tried out TikZ but I don't really know in which direction I should go or which packages I should choose...

Would another software be more helpful for my needs or can you recommend some easy to handle packages for TikZ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Given the deadline and the nature of your diagrams, I would not use TiKz this time. Geogebra and friends can be useful if you think you'll be able to express your graphics algebraically, but what I see is more a "freehand" drawing. I would go for inkscape, exporting to latex (or even tikz) in order to typeset the labels and formulae in a style consistent with the rest of the paper.

Comment: You can check and the jpgfdraw, quite simple, without much difficulty in learning http://www.dickimaw-books.com/apps/jpgfdraw/